# Why is a 2D array used to store organised point clouds and how does this structure keep neighbouring points together?

Tags: arrays, cloud, point, point-clouds

An unorganised point cloud is just a list of the coordinates of points.
An organised point cloud stores the coordinates in a 2D array instead and this is meant to help preserve the spatial topology of points, keeping neighbours close to each other.

I am confused as to how using a 2D array to store a pointcloud accomplishes this.